# How do I login to private Docker Registry with a self signed cert using WSL2 on Windows?

Tags: ssl, docker, self-signed-certificate, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a private Docker registry that uses https and a self signed certificate. I have this working on my OSX machine by adding the certificate to The keychain. However, I would not like to connect to it from a Windows Machine with WSL2.

I tried adding the cert to `certlm` and I tried to restart Docker but it didn't seem to help. Since this was WSL I tried also adding the crt file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` but neither of these prevent...

```
docker login https://...:5000
Error response from daemon: Get "https://...:5000/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

What do I need to be able to use the Docker cli from WSL2 (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to have my certificate file under "Trusted Root Certification". I had it under personal since it was managed by myself. Is there a way to still have it work while not putting it as a root cert?